# Why the song doesn't play when the next song at the listbox is selected?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, listbox

This code plays the next song at the listbox

```
 If AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState = WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped Then
        If listTracks.SelectedIndex < listTracks.Items.Count - 1 Then
            listTracks.SelectedIndex = 0
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = listTracks.Items(0)
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
        Else
            listTracks.SelectedIndex = listTracks.SelectedIndex + 1
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = listTracks.Items(listTracks.SelectedIndex)
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
        End If
End if
```

I dont get an error but the next song doesn't play

Comment: Have you checkek listTracks.Items(listTracks.SelectedIndex) retuns a valid audio file.

Comment: Yup.The audio file is valid

Comment: Does your `ListBox` list the actual full path to the file?

Comment: then  one possilility is that your code isn't reached that AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState isn't stopped, set there a halting point and see what the state is

Comment: the listbox contains the full path

Comment: `Private Sub AxWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(sender As Object, e As _WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent) Handles AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.PlayStateChange`this is the sub that executes the code inside it when the playstate changes